# Connecting html form to php via jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, database

Hey so i'm fairly new to programming and I've been learning about databases primarily with java. I've gotten used to utilizing a mysql database for my java projects but now I have to use a database using html/javascript. I can't seem to get this to work. I have some experience in html/css/javascript but little beyond the basics here. I'm using a php file to try and insert data into my database. This file currently looks like this:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('test@localhsot', 'root', '');

if (!$con) {
echo 'not connected to server';
}

if (!mysqli_select_db($con, 'testdb')) {
echo 'database not selected';
}
$Name = $_POST['username'];
$Email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO test (Name,Email) VALUES('$Name', '$Email')";

if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
echo 'Not Inserted';
} else {
echo 'inserted';
}
header("refresh:2; url=index.html");
?>
```

based on some websites and videos ive seen. From what I understand I need to use ajax(via jquery?) to send the data from my html form to the php file. I've messed around with different things ive seen online but cant figure this out. While i have some experience with html and javascript i have none with ajax and php so this is new territory. the following is the simple html form im trying to submit right now:

```
<body>

<form>
    <label>username<input type="text" ></label>
    <label>email<input type="text"></label>
    <input type="submit" value="Insert" id="submit_btn">
</form>

<script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

can anyone show me or point me to an explanation of how to make the bridge between html and php with ajax that someone without experience using it could grasp? Thank you.

Comment: Check out these resources here:
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ ,   
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ ,     
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Answer (score 0):

it quit simple to work with ajax. just follow the code

```
var data ={
"user":"somethingf"
}

login(data){

    return jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "http://someurl or ip ",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        async: false
    });
  }
```